# a for loop that won't pass beyond the first item in python

Tags: python

I have this simple average function and when its run with a test data, will show the length of the data, but when calculating the actual average just won't go beyond the first item in the sequence.   I need help in finding what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance  for taking the time to answer if you do.

```
def avg(seq):
    total = 0
    for i in seq:

        total+=i

        average = total/len(seq)
        return (float(average))

test_data = (12,89,90)
print(len(test_data))
print(avg(test_data))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong:

```
def avg(seq):
    total = 0
    for i in seq:
        total+=i
        average = total/len(seq)
        return (float(average))
```

This is right:

```
def avg(seq):
    total = 0
    for i in seq:
        total += i
    average = total / len(seq)
    return average
```

Or, if you haven't upgraded to 3.x yet,

```
average = float(total) / len(seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using standard python functions instead,

```
>>> seq = (12,89,90)
>>> sum(seq)
191
>>> float(sum(seq))/len(seq)
63.666666666666664
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, Daniel, But I want to know what I am doing here if any. cause my code produces this weird output.

Answer (score 0):

When you put a return in a function, it exits the function completely.  Pull your loop to outside of the function, or return a tuple/list outside of the `for` loop.